# Defining TypeScript variable type function or string

Tags: function, types, typescript

I have this interface:

```
interface IParameters {
    form: number;
    field: string;
    ...
}
```

I want the `form`property to be number or function and `field` to be string or function.

I try something like this:

```
interface IParameters {
    form: number | Function;
    field: string | Function;
    ...
}
```

I need this because in my code i use this variables like this:

```
var form = (typeof _oParameters.form === "function" ? _oParameters.form() : _oParameters.form);
var field = (typeof _oParameters.field === "function" ? _oParameters.field() : _oParameters.field);
```

I don't want change this variable in all my code from string/number to default function and to prevent setting this variables to other types.

but if I try to call one of this two variable like function:

```
var param:IParameters;
param.form();
...
```

I get this error:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.

but `param.form = 12;` works.

The only solution that i have found is to declare `form` and `field` to `any` type.

Is other way to define this variable without `any` type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps if you define your union type using a call signature rather than `Function`, like so...

```
interface IParameters {
    // form is of type function that returns number, or number literal.
    form: () => number | number;

    // field is of type function that returns a string, or string literal.
    field: () => string | string;
}

class Foo {
    constructor (param: IParameters) {
        var x = typeof param.form === "number" ? param.form : param.form();
        var y = typeof param.field === "string" ? param.field : param.field();
    }
}
```

Here, I am still checking `form` and `field` using `typeof`, however TypeScript is happy for it to be either a function call, or a value.

Answer (score 19):

If you try to use the code from seriesOne you will notice, that you cannot assign `form` (or `field`) a value that isn't a function.
You would get a
`Type '{ form: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IParameters'.
  Types of property 'form' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '() => string'.`

I found that using `form: (() => string) | string;` resolves this problem.

You can try the code at [the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IParameters%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20form%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20string%20%7C%20string%3B%20%2F%2Fcomment%20to%20try%20the%20working%20version%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fform%3A%20(()%20%3D%3E%20string)%20%7C%20string%3B%20%2F%2Funcomment%20to%20try%20the%20working%20version%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20strFunct()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20'Hello%20TypeScript'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20paramA%3A%20IParameters%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20form%3A%20strFunct%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20paramB%3A%20IParameters%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20form%3A%20'Hello%20stackoverflow'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(param%3A%20IParameters)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20x%20%3D%20typeof%20param.form%20%3D%3D%3D%20'string'%20%3F%20param.form%20%3A%20param.form()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Working sample:

```
    interface IParameters {
        form: (() => string) | string;
    }

    function strFunct(): string {
        return 'Hello TypeScript';
    }

    function test() {
        let paramA: IParameters = {
            form: strFunct
        }

        let paramB: IParameters = {
            form: 'Hello stackoverflow'
        }
    }

    class Foo {
        constructor(param: IParameters) {
            var x = typeof param.form === 'string' ? param.form : param.form();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Woah! Th parenthesis between the function on `IParameters` did the trick!!

Comment: This. Oddly if you write ()=>string|string the compiler will allow it but classes which consume it will only expect ()=>string and will not be allowed to pass a string literal. On the other hand if you reverse the order and write string|()=>string typescript won't parse it. Putting the parentheses around the call signature it fixes both cases.

Answer (score 2):

**Upd**
That behavior appears to be an issue [#3812](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3812) with TypeScript.
It is to be fixed as a part of TypeScript 2.0 according to the milestone assigned.

**Original answer**

You could use `instanceof` as a type guard like

```
var field = (_oParameters.field instanceof Function ? _oParameters.field() : _oParameters.field);
```

Comment: if i use your code i get the same error `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.` with this define `form: number | Function;`

Comment: You're right. That appeared to be an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3812) with TypeScript. It'll hopefully be fixed at v2.0.

Comment: is it fixed now?