# Typescript define property in interface which is of type string | () => string gives "cannot invoke expression error"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have defined an interface like described here [Defining TypeScript variable type function or string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286625/defining-typescript-variable-type-function-or-string)

It is looking like this:

```js
type displayWithFn<T> = (value: T) => string;
export interface Value<T> {
  value: T,
  displayValue: string | displayWithFn<T>;
}
```

In my code I have a function

```js
getDisplayValue(item: Value<T>): string {
    
    if (typeof item.displayValue === 'string') {
      return item.displayValue  as string;
    } else {
      return item.displayValue(item.value);
    }
  }
```

the second line `item.displayValue(item.value)` does give me the error "TS2349 cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type string | displayWithFn has no compatible call signatures."

My TypeScript version is 3.5.3.

Somebody an idea?

Comment: do you still get the error once changed to `=== 'string'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce that issue in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.5.1&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAJglgZzAGwIYgOp2ACwGIB2APACoB8UAvFABQBuqyArhAFxQkCUVFCwATnAIBzANwAocRAAeYAPb9gUIcAj8AZqgDG0AGqMWpCgG9xUKA2ZsOAGjOxEKdPqvs+gkVAA+DpGkzY+MTkEgC+kupMBFrAcHIEUMIQwAAijv4uhuQ02BAAtuyZEEacbgJCwlCm5uZw6rSgkHL1uXkAdPB+zgbQlH1QAOTuFQPc1TUT-MlM-AmtHendVuaoCFDDIhIToVAQyAjQ4xPmU8Azc6rtnU4gRTmXbZYsnFs14aFAA) with the following code:

```js
type displayWithFn<T> = (value: T) => string;

export interface Value<T> {
  value: T,
  displayValue: string | displayWithFn<T>;
}

function getDisplayValue<T>(item: Value<T>): string {
    if (typeof item.displayValue === 'string') {
        return item.displayValue  as string;
    } else {
        return item.displayValue(item.value);
    }
}
```

Let me know if the above solves your issue.

Comment: It's reproducible if you leave the type check as `=== 'strubg'`

Comment: Ah yes, good point. I had assumed that was a typo when writing the stack overflow question, but perhaps that is really present in the OP's code.

Comment: @Teneff, I think it `strubg` should be `string` because as per `interface`, `displayValue` can be `string` or `displayWithFn<T>`. **Perfeps 'strubg' is there in OP's code**  then if `typeof item.displayValue !== 'strubg'` it can be `string` or `displayWithFn<T>`. So compiler will show error because it will also check possibility for `string` which is not `expression`.

Comment: @Karan yes, it should be, but it's not, and this is the reason the OP to get the error

Comment: That was indeed a typo. Sorry for that - I updated my question

Comment: It is working in the playground. Mhh probably then just my IDE is giving me a wrong error message. Thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you can figure out the issue in your IDE!